# create textfile for local data storage? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hey guys I am new to flutter and at the moment I make an app where I want to storage my sensor data, that I get via BLE, permanent in a text file. My Question is if anyone of you has a link or an example how I can do this because my own research didn't really come up with anything useful

So I get my data like this:
[image]

I would be very thankful for any help

Comment: You want to save your data in your app storage or in a text file?

Comment: Here, from the official documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: in a textfile because when I can save them  I want to  create a table and statistics with the data. Or do you think the app storage is better for my use

Comment: There are many possible solutions: 1) you could just store it in the file 2) you can store it in an internal database and export it when necessary 3) you can store it in the app and create statistics directly in the app. There's no right or wrong.

Comment: I think 3 would be the best for me, do you might have an example link for me. I would be very grateful